# ASP.net linkbutton 'onclick' does not trigger if it is used as an AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger in UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, updateprogress

I was hoping someone can help me in this odd behavior of asp.net. I have an UpdatePanel control with two linkbutton as triggers. The triggers work fine individually. But when I have a function that calls one 'onclick' event after another (the order doesn't matter), the second linkbutton's 'onclick' event does not execute. If only one of the triggers are present in the UpdatePanel, the whole process executes successfully - but the Ajax progress panel obviously does not display for the second event - which defeats the whole purpose of making this more complicated than it should.

What's even more puzzling is that the 'onclientclick' event of the second control executes fine - only the 'onclick' event; which performs the partial postback does not execute.

Please refer to my code below:

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Content template here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lButton1" EventName="Click"/>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lButton2" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <!-- Progress template here -->
        </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress> 


<asp:LinkButton ID="lButton1" runat="server" onclick="Event1" OnClientClick="clientEvent1();">Go!</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lButton2" runat="server" onclick="Event2" OnClientClick="clientEvent2();">Go2</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void Event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Actions here

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(),"triggerEvent2", "triggerEvent2();", true);
}

public void Event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Actions here
}
```

Javascript:

```
function triggerEvent2() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('<%=lButton2.UniqueID%>');
    btn.click();
}
```

From the code above, the last part 'btn.click();' never executes - but whatever else I put in the function triggerEvent2() executes fine (and the onclientclick event executes!) which tells me at least the process is working.

If anyone is wondering what I'm doing, I just want to update the texts I have in the UpdateProgress while I'm doing multiple events in the Code behind. I would have thought there would be an easy 'update progress refresh' option while doing tasks in the code behind by now; but apparently there is none so I'm forced to do it this way.

If anyone can point out what's wrong, or can point me to the right direction, you will be my life saver!

Comment: Can you please verify that above code works correctly without update panel? Please remove update panel for testing and check if it works as expected. Then we will make it work with update panel.

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks for the quick response! Do you mean to say if it works without Ajax altogether? Then the answer is yes. Without the update panel and progress, the events executes one after the other and I get the correct result. Actually, it still works with Ajax as long as there is only one AsyncPostBackTrigger - in which case I get Ajax for the first event and none on the second event. The issue happens if there is more than one AsyncPostBackTrigger. If the triggers are 'PostBackTrigger' and not Async, the process also works but obviously the update progress never shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, add your javascript function as below, it should work.

```
//On Page Load.
CallMe();

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    CallMe();           
}

function CallMe()
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: I think you're closer to the answer. Adding this make the process work! But the Update Progress is not triggered on the 'CallMe()' event. What I have in that function is to simulate the click event on the second linkbutton. So with that added, it's the same as not having the AsyncPostBackTrigger on the second linkButton...

Comment: Well this is javascript function. Update progress works when you click on server side control.

Comment: Ok I may have reached the limit of my webdev understanding. Isn't a linkButton a server side control? If I click each button individual, they both trigger the update progress. is there a functional difference between programatically invoking a click event and a user actually clicking the button?